# Is this a first order sentence over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $A$ be an integer matrix, $z \in \mathbb{Q}^n$, $a$ an integer vector and $z_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Consider the statement:

The inequality $a\cdot x \leq z_0$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ if and only if exists a row vector $c$ with nonnegative entries such that $cA = a$ and $cz \leq z_0$

Is this statement a first order logic statement over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I'm very confused on distinguish first order logic statements. It is not clear to me in particular because I'm considering integers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as standard scalar product

Comment: Are you asking if the integers are first order definable in $\Bbb Q$? I guess it's not the case.

Comment: no. I'm asking if that statement with that context is first logic.

Comment: I have some trouble distinguishing first order logic statements.

Comment: As it stands, you can interpret it in a *two sorted* first order language, the two sorts being $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: For example, somebody said to me that totally ordered divisible groups are first logic equivalent to $(\mathbb{Q},<,+,0)$. I can put any such group instead of Q and still get a valid statement?

Comment: First order logic consists of a set of restricted syntax: $\forall$,$\exists,\lor,\land,\lnot,\implies,\iff,a,b,c,\dots,A(\cdot),B(\cdot),\dots$. To write a statement in the language or first order logic, you need to be able to express whatever it is you are trying to write using those symbols.

Comment: @Berci One **can** define $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q$ in a first-order way; this is a well-known fact proved for the first time by Julia Robinson in 1949. For a modern proof see for example [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3424).

Comment: @user400188 Even more needs to be said, mainly, over which language are we working in? The language of fields? Or maybe the language of ordered fields? This distinction is important, although I think that the question as stated doesn't require a specific language to which translate the given statement.